# Ubuntu 13.04 does not boot after install - Single disk no Windows

Tags: boot, 13.04

Hi I have a HP Elite 7300 series desktop PC with EFI bios, no legacy bios option. I have created following partitions on my 80GB disk and installed Ubuntu 13.04. EFI partition is flagged as boot. I have selected `Something else` option and selected first ext4 as `/` partition and second ext4 as `/home`. Installation went fine and rebooted my PC but did not boot. Rebooted with my USB again and tried to run `Boot-Repair`. It did run without any problem but again I was not able to boot again:
[image: gparted disk map]
Here is the report generated by `Boot-Repair`:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5639288/
I am frustrated. please help.

**Edit:**
13.04 sucks! Returning to 12.10
**Edit 2**
I have used an other PC with legacy bios to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my hard drive and then pluged in to my efi bois PC. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find an other pc with legacy bios
- Install Ubuntu 13.04 on your hard drive
- Than plugin your hard drive back to pc with efi bios.